# Countdown with jCounter offset by 1 hour in IE9 and Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown

I'm trying to implement a simple countdown timer to a specific date. I'm using the [jCounter](http://devingredients.com/jcounter/) jQuery plugin, and I believe I have everything working just fine, except that in Safari and IE9, the date is off by 1 hour. The date I'm counting down to is "08 March 2015 06:00:00" - ie. this Sunday at 6am. I'm not positive, but what I suspect is happening is that those two browsers are taking into account the Daylight Savings Time change that's happening this weekend, but I could be wrong.

Here it is on Codepen:
http://codepen.io/flysi3000/pen/myGrYG

html:

```
<div class="clock">
                <ul id="counter">
                    <li>
                        <p class="textHours">hours</p>
                        <p class="hours">00</p>
                    </li><!--
                    --><li>
                        <p class="textMinutes">minutes</p>
                        <p class="minutes">00</p>
                    </li><!--
                    --><li>
                        <p class="textSeconds">seconds</p>
                        <p class="seconds">00</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end clock -->
        </div>
```

css:

```
#counter ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#counter li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#counter .hours,
#counter .minutes,
#counter .seconds {
    font-size: 4.875em; 
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
}

#counter li p {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    line-height: .5;
}
```

js:

```
var theDate = "08 March 2015 06:00:00";
$("#counter").jCounter ({
                twoDigits: "on",
                date: theDate,
                format: "hh:mm:ss",
                timezone: "EST",
            });
```

My php isn't up to the task of changing the plugin's dateandtime.php file - does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might fix this?

Edit: I'm okay with not getting this solved in time for the countdown on Sunday am, but I'm still interested in knowing how to solve it for my own education.